# KeyError: "filename 'storages' not found"

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to load pre-trained model weights using this line :

```
state_dict = torch.load('models/seq_to_txt_state_7.tar')
```

and I'm getting:

```
       KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-3f7b5be8fc72> in <module>()
----> 1 state_dict = torch.load('models/seq_to_txt_state_7.tar')

/home/arash/venvs/marzieh_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.pyc in load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    365         f = open(f, 'rb')
    366     try:
--> 367         return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    368     finally:
    369         if new_fd:

/home/arash/venvs/marzieh_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.pyc in _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    521         # only if offset is zero we can attempt the legacy tar file loader
    522         try:
--> 523             return legacy_load(f)
    524         except tarfile.TarError:
    525             # if not a tarfile, reset file offset and proceed

/home/arash/venvs/marzieh_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.pyc in legacy_load(f)
    448                 mkdtemp() as tmpdir:
    449 
--> 450             tar.extract('storages', path=tmpdir)
    451             with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'storages'), 'rb', 0) as f:
    452                 num_storages = pickle_module.load(f)

/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.pyc in extract(self, member, path)
   2107 
   2108         if isinstance(member, basestring):
-> 2109             tarinfo = self.getmember(member)
   2110         else:
   2111             tarinfo = member

/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.pyc in getmember(self, name)
   1827         tarinfo = self._getmember(name)
   1828         if tarinfo is None:
-> 1829             raise KeyError("filename %r not found" % name)
   1830         return tarinfo
   1831 

KeyError: "filename 'storages' not found"
```

I'm using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 18.

In addition the model is saved using this function in first place:

```
def save_state(enc, dec, enc_optim, dec_optim, dec_idx_to_word, dec_word_to_idx, epoch):
state = {'enc':enc.state_dict(), 'dec':dec.state_dict(),
         'enc_optim':enc_optim.state_dict(), 'dec_optim':dec_optim.state_dict(),
        'dec_idx_to_word':dec_idx_to_word, 'dec_word_to_idx':dec_word_to_idx}
torch.save(state, epoch_to_save_path(epoch))
```

Comment: Perhaps your current working directory does not contain a folder called `storages`? You can list the folder content with `ls` or check the path of your current working directory with `pwd`.

Comment: Please assert that `storages` is in your current working directory

Comment: the result of `ls` contains a folder named `storages` in current directory @offeltoffel

Comment: is the `storages` file without any extension ? `storages` is not the same as `storages.tar`

Comment: this is confusing, you are saying `storages` is a **folder** but in row 451 you are trying to open it as if it was a file `with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'storages'), 'rb', 0) as f`. Moreover, the previous row extracts it as if it was a folder `tar.extract('storages', path=tmpdir)` see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extract)

Comment: @reportgunner it's just a folder I created in hope of solving the error. It's not a file

Comment: the source of the error is in line 450 `tar.extract('storages', path=tmpdir)`. There you try to use the folder `storages` as a file.

Comment: @SpghttCd the problem is that line 450 is not my own code. it's a class of torch libarary. my model is in `models` folder and I have nothing to do with a thing called `storages`

Comment: @reportgunner The `storages` I'm talking about, is a folder witch I created in hope of getting rid of the error. the `storage` in code...I don't know what is it? the code is inside torch library. I do'nt know why it's trying to open `storages` while my model is inside `models` folder

Comment: @MarziehHeidari are you the one calling row 1 `state_dict = torch.load('models/seq_to_txt_state_7.tar')` ? If yes, perhaps you are not specifying enough parameters or the model is not in the correct "format" / is corrupted

Comment: Ok, I see... I don't have anything to do with `pytorch`, but afaics the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extract tell, that a _tarfile_ is expected which contains a file (or TarInfo object, whatever that may be) called `storages`. Can you check if one of these is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@reportgunner is right. The model file was corrupted. End of the message!